# Is there a way to link to TSI visualization to a python application

Tags: python, azure-timeseries-insights

I am new to Time series Insights. I am curious about the python sdk to connect to TSI. I am aware that we can use the python SDK to connect to TSI and get the data in the form of a dataframe.
For my use case, I have a python flask app(UI) in which we list a set of tags that have trends in TSI. I am curious if I can embed the visualization provided in TSI into the flask app for the respective tags in the list(when the user clicks on a tag he must be provided a visualization from TSI). Does the TSI allow embedding it as an iframe. If so, what would be the API or the way to do that?

If this a no-go, then is this alternative possible?
Can we pass a tag name in a TSI API call which will directly open the visualization for that particular tag? In that case, I can make links to every tag which would take the user to the respective trend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @ks69! Currently there is no way to embed an iframe—and TSI does not have plans to enable this functionality given that it would pose a security risk. TSI requires (and will always require) that clients provide a valid access token with each query. However, you can leverage the front-end JS SDK to display charts. Take a look at the client samples [here](https://tsiclientsample.azurewebsites.net/).

Comment: The API calls to TSI will conttain the necessary authentication right. For example, access tokens. i also will use the TSIClient library to authenticate the users
Can we pass a tag name in a TSI API call which will directly open the visualization for that particular tag? In that case, I can make links to every tag which would take the user to the respective trend.

Comment: Also, I am a python developer. so is there any Python SDK for the visualizations similar to the one you shared for javascript